# Would my approach to fuzzy search, for my dataset, be better than using Lucene?

Tags: algorithm, search, lucene, fuzzy-search, similarity

I want to implement a fuzzy search facility in the web-app i'm currently working on. The back-end is in Java, and it just so happens that the search engine that everyone recommends on here, [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), is coded in Java as well. I, however, am shying away from using it for several reasons:

1. I would feel accomplished building something of my own.
2. Lucene has a plethora of features that I don't see myself utilizing; i'd like to minimize bloat.
3. From what I understand, Lucene's fuzzy search implementation manually evaluates the edit distances of each term indexed. I feel the approach I want to take (detailed below), would be more efficient.

The data to-be-indexed could potentially be the entire set of nouns and pro-nouns in the English language, so you can see how Lucene's approach to fuzzy search makes me weary.

What I want to do is take an n-gram based approach to the problem: read and tokenize each item from the database and save them to disk in files named by a given n-gram and its location.

For example: let's assume `n = 3` and my file-naming scheme is something like: `[n-gram]_[location_of_n-gram_in_string].txt`.

The file `bea_0.txt` would contain:

```
bear
beau
beacon
beautiful
beats by dre
```

When I receive a term to be searched, I can simply tokenize it in to n-grams, and use them along with their corresponding locations to read in to the corresponding n-gram files (if present). I can then perform any filtering operations (eliminating those not within a given length range, performing edit distance calculations, etc.) on this set of data instead of doing so for the entire dataset.

My question is... well I guess I have a couple of questions.

1. Has there been any improvements in Lucene's fuzzy search that I'm not aware of that would make my approach unnecessary?
2. Is this a good approach to implement fuzzy-search, (considering the set of data I'm dealing with), or is there something I'm oversimplifying/missing?

Answer (score 3):

Lucene 3.x fuzzy query used to evaluate the [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance between the queried term and every index term (brute-force approach). Given that this approach is rather inefficient, Lucene spellchecker used to rely on something similar to what you describe: Lucene would first search for terms with similar n-grams to the queried term and would then score these terms according to a String distance (such as Levenshtein or [Jaro-Winckler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance)).

However, this has changed a lot in Lucene 4.0 ([an ALPHA preview has been released a few days ago](http://search-lucene.com/m/TyoXHH3dKY)): [FuzzyQuery now uses a Levenshtein automaton to efficiently intersect the terms dictionary](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html). This is so much faster that there is now a new [direct spellchecker](https://builds.apache.org/job/Lucene-trunk/javadoc/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/DirectSpellChecker.html) that doesn't require a dedicated index and directly intersects the terms dictionary with an automaton, similarly to FuzzyQuery.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, as you are dealing with English corpus, Lucene (or Solr but I guess you could use them in vanilla lucene) has some Phonetic analyzers that might be useful [(DoubleMetaphone, Metaphone, Soundex, RefinedSoundex, Caverphone)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.PhoneticFilterFactory)

Lucene 4.0 alpha was just released, many things are easier to customize now, so you could also build upon it an create a custom fuzzy search.

In any case Lucene has many years of performance improvements so you hardly would be able to achieve the same perf. Of course it might be good enough for your case...